# Запятая в предложении "Кто такие хипстеры и где они обитают?"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, ссп

Уважаемые пользователи, помогите, пожалуйста! Не могу самостоятельно найти ответ на свой вопрос.

Хотелось бы понять, почему отсутствует запятая в предложении "Кто такие хипстеры и где они обитают?". На мой взгляд, она там должна быть перед союзом "и", поскольку предложение, как мне кажется, сложносочинённое (в предложении 2 грамматические основы:

1. Хипстеры — подлежащее, кто такие — сказуемое
2. Они — подлежащее, обитают — сказуемое

).

В тесте, который я проходил, указано, что запятой здесь не должно быть, хотя в сложночинённых предложениях запятая ставится.
Подскажите, верно ли я рассуждаю и не ошибся ли я в выделении членов предложения (а именно что "кто такие" — это сказуемое)?

Answer (score 1):

"Кто такие хипстеры и где они обитают?" Запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация, а в побудительных предложениях могут быть и общие частицы: "Где будет собрание и кто его председатель?" — общая вопросительная интонация. http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=355

Answer (score 1):

Не ставится запятая, если обе части сложносочинённого предложения являются вопросительными.

***Когда вы придёте ещё раз и сможем ли мы встретиться?***

Можно здесь почитать: [Знаки препинания в сложном предложении](https://www.yaklass.ru/materiali?mode=lsntheme&themeid=83)

Грамматические основы в предложении вы определили правильно.